# month array not displaying proper value

Tags: php, arrays

i have month array like

```
$month = array(
    01 => "January",
    02 => "February",
    03 => "March",
    04 => "April",
    05 => "May",
    06 => "June",
    07 => "July",
    08 => "August",
    09 => "September",
    10 => "October",
    11 => "Novemeber",
    12 => "December"
);
```

but when i print_r this it display like this

```
Array
(
    [1] => January
    [2] => February
    [3] => March
    [4] => April
    [5] => May
    [6] => June
    [7] => July
    [0] => September
    [10] => October
    [11] => Novemeber
    [12] => December
)
```

it displaying sept as 0 and the month of august is not dispalying.

can any one please tell me what is the problem with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nubmber starting from 0 are interpreted as [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) constats.

Since `8` and `9` are not a valid digits in octal, `08` and `09` are invalid numbers and both interpreted as just `0`. "08" is string and even in case of arithmetical operations, will be interpreted as normal decimal integer:

```
"echo '08'+'08'; // 16
```

Hence using strings should be safe for your case.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding quotes:

```
$month = array(
    "01" => "January",
    "02" => "February",
    "03" => "March",
    "04" => "April",
    "05" => "May",
    "06" => "June",
    "07" => "July",
    "08" => "August",
    "09" => "September",
    "10" => "October",
    "11" => "Novemeber",
    "12" => "December"
);
```